# What is a word for food including meat?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

**Is there a word meaning '*a person who eats meat and/or fish*'?**

For example a vegan is '*a person who does not eat or use animal products*', a vegetarian is '*a person who does not eat meat or fish*', and a pescatarian is '*a person who does not eat meat but does eat fish*'.

There is '*omnivore*', but this seems to go with '*herbivore*' and '*carnivore*' rather than *'vegan/vegetarian/pescatarian*'.

Comment: Does this mean they only eat meat and no plant food? How about fish, do they not eat fish?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, they do eat non-meat products, and fish.  Basically not preferential about the meat (or not) content of their food.

Comment: _omnivore_ is a perfectly acceptable term for this description, and it is used regularly.

Comment: @RamonMelo I agree, but I am curious as to whether there is a word following the same pattern as '*-an*'

Comment: Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117375/hypernym-for-veg-and-non-veg/117377

Comment: I eat meat and vegetables, but not fish. Does that make me an anti-pescatarian?

Comment: Don't militant vegetarians have a derogatory term they use for the rest of us?

Comment: @Davo that's more of a personal taste, right? rather than moral/religious reasons?

Comment: Yes, but I'd still be interested in a term for the practice, regardless of the cause. This way, when I am yet again offered *Taste this fish, I just **know** you'll love it*, I can reply *Sorry, I'm an anti-pecatarian* - or similar. :)

Comment: @Davo - Instead of the *non-* form (again from Latin), one could use *apo-* from Greek, meaning "*away from*": **apopescatarian** - dislike of fish.  Be warned: this is a [hybrid word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word), with both Latin and Greek roots which some people dislike, despite **automobile** (*autos* - Greek, *mobilis* - Latin), **metadata** (*meta* - Greek, *data* - Latin) and **television** (*tele* - Greek, *visio* - Latin) being others.

Comment: @GEdgar - yes, but they tend to be things like '*murderer of innocent flesh*' and suchlike (quote from a [Zits book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zits), not sure which).

Comment: "Apopescatarian" - invokes the image of a Papal Scatologist. *And I like that!*

Answer (score 6):

> **[non-vegetarian](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/non-vegetarian)** (noun ) (*[OxfordDictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/non-veggie)*)
>
> *A person who is not a vegetarian; **a meat-eater**.*
>
> **non-veggie** (noun) = **non-vegetarian.**

Comment: The irony: you've suggested "non-vegetarian", and the definition has actually used what is, in my opinion, a better term: "meat-eater".

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use the prefixed word *non-vegetarian*:

> Vegetarians also frequently stay with *non-vegetarian* friends, or lodge with others who do not understand how to provide for them.

(source: The Allinson Vegetarian Cookery Book by Thomas R. Allinson)

Comment: So there's not *actually* a word for it?  Is this because it is seen as the norm, and it is expected that people will be non-vegetarian unless otherwise specified?

Comment: I think so (but I have no concrete evidence to back it up).

Comment: Interesting.  Since there's '*straight*' for '*non-gay*', although '*straight*' is sometimes regarded as the default...

Comment: @marcellothearcane no, yes, yes. Vegetarianism as a _culture_ (not only as an eating habit) is very young in comparison with the English language, it is natural that its own vocabulary is still being created.

Comment: @marcellothearcane also "straight" stemmed from the belief that being gay is a deviant behavior. Since most people don't really associate vegetarianism or non-vegetarianism with moral standards, there wasn't the same _urge_ to invent a word for this meaning.

Answer (score 2):

How about **meat eater**?

:a person whose diet includes meat.
"if you're a meat eater, make sure you experience one of the steakhouses" [Webster's]

Answer (score 1):

WordPhD says the [hypernyms](http://wordphd.com/hypernyms-of/vegetarian) of *vegetarian* are:

> eater, 
>   feeder

If you follow the hyponyms of *[eater](http://wordphd.com/hypernyms-of/eater)* at the same site, you'll get quite a few, including

> vegetarian, 
>   omnivore

Although the OP discarded *omnivore*, it would be readily accessible to the hearer as being in the same class of word as *vegetarian*.

If an animal eats meat but occasionally eats grains or berries, there exists some debate as to whether it is a carnivore or an omnivore.

> Urging us to rethink the “dogma” of dogs as **omnivores**, Dr. Wouter Hendriks of Utrecht University’s veterinary school in the Netherlands laid out a detailed and ultimately convincing argument in favor of canine **carnivorous**-ness at the Waltham International Nutritional Sciences Symposium in Portland, Ore. [citation](http://www.vetstreet.com/our-pet-experts/are-dogs-carnivores-heres-what-new-research-says)

While it is never in doubt that dogs eat meat, there is some question as to whether they are carnivores or omnivores.

Answer (score 1):

**Vegetarian** has the roots:

> **vegetare** (from Latin) + **-arian** (Latin *-arius*, meaning having a concern or belief in a specified thing.)

**Pescatarian** has the roots:

> **Piscis** (from Latin), which is the root for the Italian, **pesce** and the *-tarian* pattern from **vegetarian**

Considering the Latin for meat is **cibum**, which forms **carnis** (think carnivore, carnage, etc) it follows that a meat-eater should be **carnitarian**, from **carnis** and the same *-tarian* pattern from vegetarian and pescatarian.  However, this implies a diet exclusively of meat, which is not the desired word.  Therefore one should consider:

> **Omnitarian**, from the Latin **omnis** meaning "*all; of all things.*"

Obviously these seem to follow the pattern of **carnivore** and **omnivore**, which already fit this meaning and are therefore redundant.  Ultimately there isn't any point in making up *omnitarian*, and it's highly unlikely to catch on - but still, should someone require it, it does make sense!

---

Definitions from the [Google](https://google.com) dictionary, which I believe is from the [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com).

Comment: 1. Unfortunately omnivore means someone who eats both plants and animals while given its roots it should mean one who eats everything. Perhaps omnitarian could be used to refer to one who eats everything.
2. It wouldn't be "omnitarian", as the suffix to denote "one who practices or believes in something" is not "-tarian" but rather "-arian". When words end in "-tarian" it's because their root word ends in "-ty" (e.g. humanity->humanitarian, authority=>authoritarian). That leaves us with "omniarian" which is just a prefix and a suffix with no root and therefore doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding 2, before one starts creating words, a knowledge of Latin and word construction is useful :)